# What is the purpose of .desktop files?

Tags: files, cleanup, ardour

I installed Ardour 6.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. It apparently created and placed a ardourxxxxx.desktop file on my desktop. What's the deal with these files? Is it a shortcut? Should/Can I erase it?

The application was installed via a downloaded installer from the Ardour website, and not through the usuall apt command.

Comment: This is a desktop shortcut. It can be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

The installer on the website is a generic Linux installation and does not cater for specifc desktops. Open a terminal and

```
cd Desktop
sudo desktop-file-install ardourxxxxx.desktop
```

Replace `ardourxxxxx.desktop` with the actual filename, and enter your password when prompted.
This will add Ardour to the desktop so it will show up on the Applications screen.

Comment: Handy. I didn't know about desktop-file-install. Usually I just move the .desktop file into ~/.local/share/applications manually.  (You'd think this sort of thing would be a context menu option, or drag-drop function...)

Answer (score 1):

Files with .desktop extensions are launchers for applications. Here's a general tutorial on the topic.

https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-desktop-shortcut/